# Multisite configuration Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new at Drupal and i'm facing a issue related to the tree using multisites.

My current tree is this way:

```
__docroot
  |__sites
     |__all
     |__site1
        |__src
           |__modules
           |__themes
           |__settings.php
```

and i would like to know where do i set to Drupal see the `site1` and expose the site to be acess by `localhost`

**I can't change** the folder structure to remove the `src` because its a repository setting.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 it's supposed to be like following. And it's not object-orientied. So no `src/Controller` etc.

`sites/all` carries all contrib and custom themes and modules that are enablable by every multi-site instance individually.

```
__docroot
  |__sites
     |__all
     |  |__modules
     |  |  |__contrib
     |  |  |  |__devel
     |  |  |  |__views
     |  |  |__custom
     |  |     |__my_module_abc
     |  |     |__my_module_xyz
     |  |__themes
     |     |__contrib
     |     |  |__bootstrap
     |     |__custom
     |        |__my_bootstrap_subtheme
     |__default
     |  |__files
     |  |__settings.php
     |__site1
     |  |__files
     |  |__settings.php
     |__site2
        |__files
        |__settings.php
```

In Drupal 8 it's a little bit different and it's object-oriented.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware that is the correct way to keep organized and working but since the repo gives me the project as `site1>src>settings.php, files..` i dont know how can i change to Drupal see my enviroment and work correctly

Comment: @SofiaLunkes – What repo? Something public?

Comment: not, this is private =/ i can only provide these informations about the repository